# Plesk 9 VPS - Doesn't reply to NameServer requests (nslookup, etc)

Tags: nameserver

I'm trying to troubleshoot a problem with a new VPS i'm setting up.

The VPS is running Plesk 9 on a CentOS 5 system.

Everything works fine, except it doesn't serve dns requests.

If I try something like

> nslookup [somedomain.com] the.ser.ver.ip

to test a DNS query, i get the following error

> ;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

I can't telnet to it on port 42 either..

I'm guessing something is blocking the requests..

firewall maybe? the plesk firewall module is installed and the nameservers entry is green.

Any other way I can check what's blocking it on the server?

Any help/tip greatly appreciated.

Note: http works, i can telnet to the server on port 80 and i can also ping the server

Thanks

Comment: What's the output of lsof -i udp:53 ?

Comment: @Niall. Thanks for the command.. didn't know that one. See my comment below Josh's answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First try a lookup on the server itself. via SSH, execute:

```
dig @127.0.0.1 somedomain.com
```

This should produce output like:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.3.6-P1-RedHat-9.3.6-4.P1.el5_5.3 <<>> @localhost somedomain.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options:  printcmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 59457
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 3, ADDITIONAL: 6

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;somedomain.com.           IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
somedomain.com.    14400     IN      A       1.2.3.4
```

If it doesn't, check that the nameserver is actually running. You didn't specify which nameserver, but for BIND you can restart it with:

```
/etc/init.d/named restart
```

If you do get an answer, it means the name server is running. Most likely the issue is a firewall. Examine the output of `iptables --list`, looking for lines like:

```
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:domain state NEW
```

Remember you'll need both UDP and TCP ports 53. If you have lines like that, make sure that the chain is actually being used also.

Comment: Wooa, noob supreme.. I had not 'activated' the firewall rules in Plesk panel. Worked fine after that..  But I did learn something with your response so thanks anyway.. :)

Comment: Glad I could help!